# Creating a delete trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `ul_logins` and a table called `userbase` and `userchanges`. I know, want, whenever I delete some user from `ul_logins` a trigger to automatically delete the same user from `userbase` and `userchanges`. The id of the user is `id` at `ul_logins` and `userID` at `userbase` and `userchanges`

I have written this trigger in mysql (phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deleteUser AFTER DELETE ON ul_logins
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM userbase WHERE userID = :old.id;
END
```

But it doesn't work, I get an error all the time. But I just can't find what the problem is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'TRIGGER deleteUser AFTER DELETE ON ul_logins
>   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>   DELETE FROM us' at line 1

I already googled and there was another solution and tried this

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER deleteUser AFTER DELETE ON ul_logins
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM userbase WHERE userID = :old.id;
END;|

DELIMITER ;
```

but this didn't work neitehr. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS deleteUser;

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER deleteUser AFTER DELETE ON ul_logins
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DELETE FROM userbase WHERE userID = old.id;
END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So the only thing I did wrong was the OR REPLACE? Or Am I seeing something wrong there? And yes, this works, thanks.

Comment: @loomie you're welcome :) yes i don't think it's possible to use OR REPLACE, and also the old value of id is `old.id` and not `:old.id`