# Mysql unknown column error in delete trigger

Tags: mysql

When I run:

```
DELETE FROM `examplecompname_empdata` WHERE `Emp_ID` = '1'
```

I get the following error: `Unknown column 'examplecompname_empdata.Emp_ID' in 'where clause'`.

I have 2 tables `examplecompname_empdata` and `triggertable`.
I've already created a delete trigger, when i delete a data in `examplecompname_empdata` it must delete the same id in `triggertable`.
But after i click the delete data in my dashboard it says:

```
Unknown column 'examplecompname_empdata.Emp_ID' in 'where clause'
DELETE FROM `examplecompname_empdata` WHERE `Emp_ID` = '1'
```

I create the trigger on  `examplecompname_empdata` with this code:

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM triggertable

WHERE triggertable.id = examplecompname_empdata.Emp_ID;

END
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It's been a while since I've last used SQL, but `table.Emp_ID` is a column in the `table`. Are you sure you have this column? PHPMyAdmin seems to be telling you that you don't have it, maybe there's a typo

Comment: Where is the id you want to delete in the second delete statement? Provide a complete code example.

Comment: sorry. my table examplecompname_empdata id is "Emp_ID" and triggertable id is "id" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367041/creating-a-delete-trigger) i used that link for basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you the `AFTER DELETE` statement in trigger definition.

```
// begining codes.....FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM triggertable

   WHERE triggertable.id = OLD.Emp_ID; // not the table.id 

END
```

See [MYSQL DELETE TRIGGER](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_delete.php)